# Bitcoin Core Offline Reinstallation

Tags: backup, offline

It is possible to reinstall Bitcoin Core Offline? I copied all the files to my external HDD. I use Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by copy? do you have tar file?

Comment: I downloaded the complete node until today, but I don't have much more space on my disk to store it. I want to save it in order to re-install the program in the future not from beginning, but from the point I have stopped synchronization.

Comment: my answer should help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you have tar.gz file do like that to extract files:

- `tar xzf bitcoin-0.14.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

install it

- `sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-0.14.2/bin/*`

finally, run it

- `bitcoind -daemon`

if you mean by "you copied all the files" that you copied `.bitcoin` directory so do like that after the previous step:

- `mkdir ~/.bitcoin`

move the files you copied to this directory and execute

- `bitcoind -daemon`